# How to Cancel a request in GRPC flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, protocol-buffers, grpc

I recently migrated from using the **dio** package for REST API in flutter to GRPC. I successfully implemented the cancel token which cancels a request sent with **dio**. However since GRPC is different am finding it hard to **cancel** a GRPC request.

I have a grpc interceptor , a custom wrapper that handles all grpc errors

Can anyone help me out with a single code base that can cancel **any unary calls** for Grpc in Flutter.

None of the solutions provided so far solved my issue

My code is uses MVVM architecture with Getit which is structured into data source , repository  , service and view models .

Please note ... The error handling occurs extensively in the Repository where a custom error wrapper is defined to catch the errors.

```
    Example data source
    
        abstract class ExampleDataSource {
          Future<void> someMethod();
        
        }
        
        @LazySingleton(as: ExampleDataSource)
        class ExampleDataSourceImpl extends ExampleDataSource {
          final SomeGrpcClient client = SomeGrpcClient(
              someClientChannel.initializeWithHostAndPort(address:"address")!,
              interceptors: [interceptor]);
        
          @override
          Future<void> someMethod() async {
        //asyncFunctionWrapper is used to check internet connection
            return await asyncFunctionWrapper.handleAsyncNetworkCall(() async {
              return await client.someGrpcRequest();
            
            });
          }
        }
    
    //Example repository
    
        abstract class ExampleRepo {
      Future<Either<CustomError, void>> someMethod();
    
    }
    
    @LazySingleton(as: ExampleRepo)
    class ExampleRepoImpl extends ExampleRepo {
      final ExampleDatasource exampleDs;
      ExampleRepoImpl(this.exampleDs);
    
      @override
      Future<Either<CustomError, void>> someMethod() async {
//customRepositoryWrapper is a wrapper that catches grpc errors and returns it to the CustomError
        return await customRepositoryWrapper.wrapError(function: () async {
          return await exampleDs.someMethod();
        });
      }
    
    }
    
    //Example service
        abstract class ExampleService {
      Future<Either<CustomError, void>> someMethod();
    
    }
    
@LazySingleton(as: ExampleService)
class ExampleServiceImpl extends ExampleService {
  final ExampleRepo exampleRepo;
  ExampleServiceImpl(this.examplRepo);

  @override
  Future<Either<CustomError, void>> someMethod() async {

      return await exampleRepo.someMethod();
   
  }

}
```

Now with this set up , i call the service inside a view model . My issue is setting up a cancel request which does not care which unary call is made , it will cancel the request. Unlike using the **cancelToken** to **dio** package where you can easily cancel request during a network call. I want to achieve same results with GRPC

Comment: doesn't client.someGrpcRequest() return a call which has a cancel() method?

Comment: no there is no call that cancels it from the client

Comment: so when and where do you want to cancel it?

Comment: I want to be able to cancel it when the method in the service is called .For instance i show a loading overlay with a cancel button which should be able to cancel the request that i make  .